# Code review of a branch in GitHub

Tags: git, github, branch

I need to do a code review of a whole branch in GitHub. I went to the [branches page](https://github.com/rails/rails/branches) and hit [compare](https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/master...3-1-stable). There's a tab there, files changed, that shows exactly what I need, the diff between the two branches, master and the selected one. The problem is that it doesn't allow you to comment on code like a [single diff does](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/5f6accf8cad1e7a116421a95d09fabfca254ad0b):

[image: github code review interface]

The blue bubble just doesn't appear on the branch diff page.

Does anybody know how to perform a code review of a whole branch in GitHub?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently there's no UI to write comments on a branch diff. My solution for now was asking the other programmer to do a pull request. It *did* work to do a pull request from one project to itself and in the pull request I can write comments.

Comment: I think that is good solution to your problem. This way you comment on a specific revision in the other branch, so you have less problems when there are new commits to that branch.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have known already that `you could comment on each commit` by clicking on the commit link. Not answering your question on the whole files compare as in pull request but I do hope this is useful for someone else.